# Jquery loop through each li for each ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently have a loop like this which goes through each li, and looks for certain content in the Li and adds a class. The problem is that the layout has multiple UL's i.e. So I want it to find the li within each of the UL's. Right now it stop the first instant it finds any li with matches my IF criteria.

```
 var list = $('.sampleAddress li span');
  $(list.get().reverse()).each(function () {
  var currentLine = $(this).html();
  var unmatched = unmatchedLine;
   if (currentLine.indexOf(unmatched) !== -1) {
       $(this).html($(this).text().replace("  ", " ").replace("&", "&AMP;").replace(unmatchedLine.toUpperCase(), '<span class="matchedClass">' + unmatchedLine.toUpperCase() + '</span>'));
           return false;
       }
  });
```

Layout of HTML is as follows

```
<ul class="boxSlider">
<li>
    <ul class="sampleAddress">
    <li><span>something</span></li>
    <li><span>something</span></li>
    <li><span>something</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <ul class="sampleAddress">
    <li><span>something</span></li>
    <li><span>something</span></li>
    <li><span>something</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What precisely is that loop doing? What are you looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a separate loop for the `ul`

```
$('.sampleAddress').each(function () {
    var list = $(this).find('li span');
    $(list.get().reverse()).each(function () {
        var currentLine = $(this).html();
        var unmatched = unmatchedLine;
        if (currentLine.indexOf(unmatched) !== -1) {
            $(this).html($(this).text().replace("  ", " ").replace("&", "&AMP;").replace(unmatchedLine.toUpperCase(), '<span class="matchedClass">' + unmatchedLine.toUpperCase() + '</span>'));
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```